# How can i retain the state of fragment when i change from a tab

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment, savestate

**Recently i create an application that execute an async task, my app has a toolbar that contains an sliding tabs, when i change my tab from first tab to second tab my async task execute over and over again, how can i avoid that?, how can i save the state of my fragment? i tried to use**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstaceState!=null){
       //TODO
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with that you have to use the save instance state..in your case you can store the data into a singleton class or a static property in the main activity, then in your fragment you create a global boolean isDataLoaded, which in case of true value you dont execute the task. to save the state of the variable just do :

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {


    outState.putBoolean("LOADDATA", isDataLoaded);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
```

Then in your createView :

```
 if(savedInstanceState != null){
        isDataLoaded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("LOADDATA");
    }
```

Comment: i tried to do that and in my create view i put a toast to show a message ,but my async task is execute over and over again :/